# openssl rsa decrypt produces gobbledygook

Tags: encryption, openssl, base64, rsa

Decrypting a message I know contains 8 numbers, actually returns 8 character gobbledygook: =ƒT|®4ê&

I first convert it from base64 with: `openssl enc -d -base64 -A -in in.txt -out rsa.txt`

And the decrypt RSA command (private key) is:

```
openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in rsa.txt -out msg.txt -inkey priv.pem -keyform PEM -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pkcs1
```

Any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: If you got 8 characters of output after RSA decryption of a PKCS1 padded ciphertext then almost certainly the decryption is correct and you don't understand the format of the plaintext.

Comment: Umm, interesting...the data is encrypted using Java on (I think) a Unix system. But I thought base64 mitigated those differences? Could the number be changed (byte order or something)?